# Show that every $x \in G\setminus \{1\}$ and every $H<G$ have infinitely many conjugates for $G$ infinite simple group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite simple group. It is requested to prove:

$(i)$ Every $x \in G\setminus \{1\}$ has infinitely many conjugates.

$(ii)$ Every non-trivial proper subgroup $H < G$ has infinitely many conjugates.

which is exercise $3.34$ from J. Rotman's An introduction to the theory of groups.

Here is what has been done:

$(i)$. Let $X = G$. Consider the action $\alpha: G \times X \to X$ given by $\alpha(g, a) = gag^{-1}$, for $a\in X$.

Note that the Orbit of $a \in X$ is
$$Orb(a) = \{\alpha(g, a) \in X: g\in G\} = \{gag^{-1} \in X: g\in G\} = a^G$$
which is the conjugacy class of $a$ in $G$, and the stabilizer of $a \in X$ is
$$G_a = \{g \in G: \alpha(g, a) = a\} = \{g \in G: ga = ag\} = C_G(a)$$
which is the centralizer of $a$ in $G$.

Then, exists an homomorphism $\phi: G \to S_{\infty}$ such that $\phi(g)(x) = \alpha(g, a)$, for every $g \in G$ and $a \in X$.

By the First Isomorphism Theory, $G/\ker(\phi) \cong Im(\phi)$.

Since $G$ is simple, $\ker(\phi) = \{1\}$ or $\ker(\phi) = G$.

From here it is not clear how to continue. Any valuable idea, hint, or solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(i)** You have $\phi:G\to S_{\mathrm{Orb}(x)}$ with $\phi(g)(a)=gag^{-1}$. If $|\mathrm{Orb}(x)|=n$ were finite, then $S_n$ would be finite, so $\phi$ would have finite image, so its kernel has finite index. But its kernel is normal, so must be trivial or all of $G$. If it were trivial, then $G$ would be isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$, hence finite, a contradiction. Thus it is all of $G$, which means $x$ is central, but then $\langle x\rangle$ is a normal (indeed, central) subgroup which must be proper (else $G=\langle x\rangle$ would not be simple, for it would have proper nontrivial normal subgroups $\langle x^n\rangle$ for any $n>1$), a contradiction.

**(ii)** Same idea, but have $G$ act on subgroups instead of elements by conjugation.

Comment: Let me know if I misunderstood in the case where $\ker \phi = G$: We know that $Z(G) \trianglelefteq G$ and $x \neq 1$ is element of $Z(G)$. Thus, $Z(G) = G$. Now, we know that $\langle x \rangle \trianglelefteq Z(G)$, but $x \neq 1$. Thus, $\langle x \rangle = G$. Which implies that the conjugacy class of $x$ generate whole $G$. Therefore, $x$ has infinitely many conjugates in $G$. Right?

Comment: There's no point to mentioning $Z(G)$. From the fact $x$ is central, it immediately follows all its powers are too, hence $\langle x\rangle$ is central, hence normal (indeed, $g\langle x\rangle g^{-1}=\langle gxg^{-1}\rangle=\langle x\rangle$ for all $g$), hence $\langle x\rangle$ must be all of $G$ (it cannot be trivial as $x\ne1$). And $\langle x\rangle=G$ infinite cyclic also contradicts simplicity. Since all roads lead to contradiction, the original assumption $n$ is finite must be wrong. (I am not sure why you're bringing up the phrase "conjugacy class" in relation to $x$ generating $G$.)

Comment: Because I was confused. But now, everything is clear as dirty water (really clear). Thanks sir!